# Realm Query Returns Incomplete Results Set In Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I have been having a very unusual behavior when using `Realm` to `insert` and `read/query` data. Here is what is happening to be precise:

**Initial Status**

When I start to insert data to the database, everything works fine. I have the following code to handle `autoIncrementingId` since I have not found a version of `Realm` that offers this out of the box!

```
CashOrder cashOrder = new CashOrder();

realm.beginTransaction();

int lastCashOrderId;
RealmResults<CashOrder> cashOrders = realm.where(CashOrder.class).findAll();

cashOrders.sort("id", Sort.ASCENDING);

if (cashOrders.isEmpty()){
    cashOrder.setId("0");
}else{
    lastCashOrderId = Integer.parseInt(cashOrders.last().getId());
    cashOrder.setId(String.valueOf(lastCashOrderId + 1));
}

//the rest of the code here 

//then copyToRealm here;

realm.copyToRealm(cashOrder);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

**The problem**

Insertion of data into the `database` works just fine but the moment the **id** value reaches `10` - implying 11 items in the table since my id starts at `(0)`, I get a `Realm Primary Key Exception` which basically complains that I am trying to add an already existing object.

I am explicitly calling `realm.copyToRealm(obj)` instead of `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj)` because that is what I want to do. Updates only are allowed when doing an **Edit**.

I am stuck here and I can't seem to figure out what is causing this issue!

**More information**

I am using:

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'
```

I will truly appreciate your help on this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because your ID is a `STRING` and therefore it's ordered äs `1`, `10`, `2`, `3`, ... `9`

Comment: Yes, using Strings for IDs and treating them as integers is asking for trouble :-)

Comment: I shot myself in the foot with that

Comment: @TimCastelijns are you available? I am kind of stuck somewhere with this migration to change type

Comment: @Eenvincible yep look here is how I changed primary key for my model https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a584a6887923b8a604fbdd8074584ba3 getNextUid is a custom method that just returns a next number

Comment: So since I already had a String id column, I don't need to remove it first?

Comment: If you change the type, you have to remove it first then add it back with correct type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120151/discussion-between-eenvincible-and-tim-castelijns).

Comment: I have done what I believe is correct here https://gist.github.com/echirchir/9af937c5ce750722a852668e928f09d5 but seems there is no Default realm configuration;

Comment: Try using the realm instance the migration method passes to you. Anyway I dont know if you can do queries while migrating..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your ID is a `STRING` and therefore it's ordered as `1`, `10`, `2`, `3`, ... `9`.

This means when you evaluate the "next ID" when you had already inserted `"10"`,

```
lastCashOrderId = Integer.parseInt(cashOrders.last().getId());
```

`lastCashOrderId` will be 9, and you'll be inserting `10` again.

Solution: use `long` id for longs, or re-think your auto-increment IDs (f.ex. use `UUID.randomString()` or something)

P.S. you should use `findAllSorted()` instead of `findAll().sort()` for consistent behavior when you update to the newer Realm versions.

EDIT: please use `long newId = realm.where(CashOrder.class).max("age").longValue() + 1;` to evaluate the new ID, and do this while you're in a transaction.

Comment: Let me give this a shot

Comment: I will just change type to long (with a migration) then see how it goes!

Comment: Migrations are giving me a hassle on this @EpicPanda; since I have the @PrimaryKey annotation, do I need to add it back using the migration since I have removed Field then added back same field?

Comment: I went to route of  long type and after a lot of work, I have it working

Comment: Disappointingly enough I just got back, even though the answer for the migration questions was right here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3068

Comment: Yeah I have figured that out! Thanks for your help

Comment: I am back, sadly, after one part of the code worked just fine; another part started failing at 13. So it tries to add 13 a second time even though the max is 14

Comment: Are you sure you evaluated the new `max` after you inserted the previous with `copy`? Re-evaluating the max should work if you do it in a transaction.

Comment: I actually got it working by doing findAllSorted("id")

Comment: Do you think by getting longValue() will help instead of just .max("id")?

Comment: Thanks mate, I will update it to use that longValue()